# Добавление записи в таблицу PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

```
$connPDO->query("INSERT INTO `project` (`ID`, `logo`, `name`, `square`, `date_start`, `fio_c`, `price_all`, `email_c`, `phone_c`, `column_ID`, `dogovor_file`, `check_files`, `anketa_file`, `acts_files`, `refence_files`, `phots_files`, `obmer_pdf`, `obmer_dwg`) VALUES (NULL, $uploadfileLogo,$namePr,$squareObject,'$dateStartPr',$fio,$pricePr,$email,$phone,1,$uploadfileDog,NULL,$uploadfileAnket,$uploadfilesActs,$uploadfilesReferences,$uploadfilesPhotos,$uploadfileObmerPDF,$uploadfileObmerDWG)");
```

Запрос написал. Но в базу не добавляет. 
Пробовал через `prepare` и `execute`, как и делал раньше, но не получается, делаю напрямую тоже самое. 
Думал может в синтаксисе проблема и кавычки значениям поставить надо, но не работает. Странное самое, что если ставить кавычки именно дате, то запрос застревает, как при ошибке, а без кавычек там, проходит и выполняется последующий *php* код, но запись не добавляется.

Вот запрос который у меня работает:

```
$stmt = $connPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `name`, `email_u`, `password_u`, `role_ID`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute([$usArr['name'],$usArr['email_u'],$usArr['pass_u'],$usArr['role_u']]);
```

Comment: На всякий случай: вы не апострофы используете, а символ на левой верхней клавише.  Это странно. Хотя может и приниматься. И код неверно включен в вопрос.

Comment: установите режим перехвата ошибок PDO в Exception. Смотрите логи

Comment: все в параметры и обновить вопрос. Очевидно, без кавычек добавить строковые значения не получится. а так по итогу после логгирования как описано выше, окажется что у вас либо число полей не соответствует, либо типы